# Should users be allowed to enter a date outside an age restriction?

Tags: forms, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I allow users to select a valid but disqualifying option?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15553/should-i-allow-users-to-select-a-valid-but-disqualifying-option)

If you have an age restriction to use your web service should the users be able to input birthday information that is outside the restriction? What are the benefits of including birthday information that is outside the age restriction and is it better user experience to include this? Will it not confuse the users?

One example of this is the facebook sign up form. They have an age restriction of 13 years but their sign up form includes all years up to this one.

Comment: I think this question has two main problems: (1) It's too localized (to facebook sign in birthday form field) and (2) its very close to a rant question (see the FAQ: http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). Youd probably have a better chance getting an answer if you revise the question to be more general.

Comment: Will try to do this.

Comment: Looking forward too it. Good luck!